# Apache benchmark HTTP GET location

Tags: apache, apachebench

I am using Apache Benchmark (ab) for stress testing my Glassfish server. The static content (which is to be downloaded) is a 50MB file binary file. I have been firing thousands of request using AB. My questions are

- Does the file get actually downloaded on the client from where the AB command is triggered?
- If yes, at what location do the files get physically downloaded (/tmp) ?
- I am worried that the client might soon run out of hard-disk space by these request.

I am running AB on a CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the file get actually downloaded on the client from where the AB
>   command is triggered?

The file gets downloaded, but is not saved in the filesystem.

> If yes, at what location do the files get physically downloaded
>   (/tmp)?

As described, this doesn't happen.

> I am worried that the client might soon run out of hard-disk space by
>   these request.

You don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it handled? The bandwidth is consumed, but the content discarded?

Comment: It looks like the content is read into a 8KB buffer in memory, which is cleared before reading the next 8KB. You can have a look at the ApacheBench source code here: https://github.com/CloudFundoo/ApacheBench-ab

Comment: U r a top guy...thnx mate!